# Plotting orbit from potential function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Suppose you have an autonomous conservative ordinary differential equation, for example: $$x'' + w^2 \sin(x) = 0$$
We can pretty easily find that the orbits satisfy the implicit equation:
$$\tfrac{y^2}{2}-w^2 \cos(x) = E$$
where E is constant.
My book proposes a graphical method to plot the orbits from the potential function $U(x) = -w^2 \cos(x)$ but the explanation they do of the method is not particularly illuminating.
Do you know any method to sketch the orbits or deduce its properties from the potential function (find bifurcation points, for example)?

I want to clarify I don't need the specific answer for this problem, I can find that with Desmos or any other software, but a method to deduce the aspect of the orbit.
Thanks in advance

Non trivial properties of the orbits can be deduced from $U(x)$ for example:

> If U(x) has a maximum at $x_0$, then the system will have a saddle point in $x_0$ (it follows from the behavior of the linearized system).

Clarification: of course, we won't be able to sketch the orbits for all levels of energy. It is sufficient to sketch orbits for a representative set of energy levels, especially bifurcation levels. In that sense, I am really interested in any technique.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible from Enegy formulation.. The energies are integrals of a higher differential order.

Assuming varying initial/boundary values, many solutions are possible. In Desmos you assumed different B.C. s

Comment: I know, just suppose we fix $E = E_0$. I don't need to know the orbit at every posible value of $E$, just in a representative small set of values of the initial energy.